# How do I replace my view model and use DTO to return to the view?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, automapper

I am new to MVC, EF and Automapper.

I have made a dto which basically takes properties from other entities.

Now, I want to map the dto to those classes using the AutoMapper which I have downloaded and registered but don't know how to use.

public BooksReadersDTO GetAllBooksReaders(int pageNo, int pageSize)
{

```
        BooksReadersDTO booksReadersViewModel = new BooksReadersDTO();
        List<BooksReadersDTO> ListBooksReaders = new List<BooksReadersDTO>();
        int rowNo = (pageNo - 1) * pageSize;

        using (BooksDbContext context = new BooksDbContext())
        {
            booksReadersViewModel.TotalRecords = context.Books.Count();

            var data = (from nt in context.BooksReaders
                        join n in context.Books
                        on nt.BooksID equals n.BooksID
                        join t in context.Readers
                        on nt.TagID equals t.TagID
                        select new BooksReadersDTO { BooksID = n.BooksID, IsPublished = n.IsPublished, BooksTitle = n.BooksTitle, TagName = t.TagName })
                        .ToList();
                                                         
            ListBooksReaders=data.OrderBy(x => x.BooksID).Skip(rowNo)
                            .Take(pageSize).ToList();
            booksReadersViewModel.ListBooksReaders = ListBooksReaders;

            return booksReadersViewModel;
        }

    }
```

Now in this code, what I believe is that this part

```
select new BooksReadersDTO { BooksID = n.BooksID, IsPublished = n.IsPublished, BooksTitle = n.BooksTitle, TagName = t.TagName })
```

can be replaced by AutoMapper but cannot figure out how.

```
namespace BooksReadersApp.App_Start
{
    public class MapperProfile: Profile
    {
        public MapperProfile() 
        {
            var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
                cfg.CreateMap<Books, BooksReadersDTO>();
                cfg.CreateMap<Readers, BooksReadersDTO>();
                cfg.CreateMap<BooksReaders, BooksReadersDTO>
            });
        }
    }
}
```

and initialized it also in application startup file in global.ascx.

How do I use it since i want to return DTO to the view instead of the ViewModel.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index(int page = 1)
        {
            int pageSize = 10;
            BooksReadersMethods BooksReadersMethods = new BooksReadersMethods();
           
            BooksReadersDTO BooksReadersViewModel = BooksReadersMethods.GetAllBooksReaders(page, pageSize);
            BooksReadersViewModel.Pager = new Pager(BooksReadersViewModel.TotalRecords, page);
            BooksReadersViewModel.Pager.CurrentPage = page;
            return View(BooksReadersViewModel);
        }
```

Comment: any help would be appreciated becuase it's been 12 hours and i am still looking to fix it but couldn't.

Comment: Can you show your view pls? What do you need a  mapper for?

Comment: @Sergey: in my view, i have just 1 html table which is filled from looping over the List returned from the action viewmodel.

Comment: i know it can be done using the viewmodel but i want to do it using the dto and automapper.

Comment: really, its making me insane.

Comment: Shouldn't `cfg.CreateMap<Books, BooksReadersDTO>();` be `cfg.CreateMap<Books, BooksDTO>();`?

Comment: yeah it should be, corrected but further i need to do full mapping.

Answer (score 0):

Map your types without AutoMapper. It really doesn't take so much effort and you keep compile time safety.

Comment: Hi. Its a requirement so i need to. Please